# Chrome Package App: opening modal windows or use bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I have written my first chrome app, but I am having an issue. I can't seem to open a modal window? Does this functionality exist or should I use bootstrap to show a modal window?

I wonder what others are doing?

I am able to open another window but both windows are active at the same time and can be changed, which is not what I want.

I am trying to create a settings menu, so a modal window would open and allow you to update and then when closing it, it would give control back to the main window.

Any ideas?

Comment: I feel like this ought to be possible, because when I go to `chrome://settings` and click `Keyboard settings` I get a modal window.

Answer (score 1):

Like browser tabs, Chrome App top-level windows have no concept of modality with respect to one another. Each lives in its own world. You have a few options:

1. Experiment with the alwaysOnTop option. See https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/window-state for an example. This might be sufficient for your needs.
2. When the window you want to be modal is open, gray out or otherwise disable the contents of the other windows. This will probably be a crappy user experience, especially if your user misplaces the window that you want topmost.
3. Instead of creating a top-level Chrome App window, use a lightbox-style div in your main window and stick the modal content in there. This is the idiomatic way to do it, as most Chrome Apps are single-page sites.

Depending on your specific use case, you can probably implement an approximation of modality  through event listeners and AppWindow.focus(). But you're not going to get any help from the system, and because you can't stop non-modal windows from being focused in the first place, it likely won't be the clean experience you have in mind.

Comment: Chrome uses #3 for its Settings. Poke around `chrome://settings` with the devtools -- `/resources/js/cr/ui/bubble.js` is interesting.

Answer (score 1):

For an extension, the idiomatic settings interface is [Options](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/options), a declaration in `manifest.json` that gives the extension an *options* link in `chrome://extensions`.

I would strongly suggest the aforementioned, but for a native app it's a no-go:

[image: options_page is only allowed for extensions]

Chrome still doesn't offer an idiomatic interface for native app settings, so it's like you said: "I wonder what others are doing."

Well... everything:

- Caret uses a menu bar to open fully configurable JSON files in an editor tab.
- Google Keep has no settings.
- Writer opens a separate tab via a tiny, oddly located gear icon.
- Chrome opens a separate tab via a 3-bar icon to the right of the omnibox.
- Sketchpad opens a sort of floating div via a 3-bar icon.
- Writebox opens a second UI bar via the 3-bar icon.

In the absence of interface guidelines, I'd model my interface after the Chrome browser, and open settings from a 3-bar icon, hopefully into a separate tab, and ideally accessible from some sort of command bar via `yourapp://settings`. (That last bit might not be possible.)

Whatever route you go, I haven't found copy/paste Chrome APIs for file menus, omnibars, or tabs, and if you want the lightbox, [`showModalDialog()`](http://dev.opera.com/articles/showmodaldialog/) is justly deprecated and [`<dialog>`](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/a-preview-of-the-new-dialog-element) is a long way off, so you'll be rolling your own solution.

Above all, I'd advise against opening a separate window. Chrome OS tends to use tabs, and where there's not a tab, there's a lightbox.

Answer (score -2):

Add to manifest.json this lines

```
"browser_action": {
"default_popup":"popup.html"
},
"options_page":"settings.html"
```

where popup.html - modal window

settings.html - settings window (show in extensions menu)

Comment: Chrome App != Chrome Extension.